# regex matching is unable to select alphanumeric string with spaces in python

Tags: python, regex, match, alphanumeric

I have the following list of expressions in python

```
LIST1=["AR BR_18_0138249",  "AR R_16_01382649",  "BR 16 0138264", "R 16 01382679" ]
```

In the above string a few patterns are alpha numeric but there is a space between the two second set of sequences. I expect the following output

```
  "AR BR_18_0138249"
  "AR R_16_01382649"
  "BR 16 0138264"
  "R 16 01382679"
```

I have tried the following code

```
import regex as re
pattern = r"(\bB?R_\w+)(?!.*\1)|(\bB?R \w+)(?!.*\1)|(\bR?^sd \w+)(?!.*\1)"
for i in LIST1:
rest = re.search(pattern, i)
if rest:
    print(rest.group(1))
```

I have obtained the following result

```
BR_18_0138249
R_16_01382649
None
None
```

I am unable to get the sequences with the spaces. I request someone to guide me in this regard

Comment: Maybe it's not a white space? Odd thing to say I know but maybe just maybe it's a different character that renders like a white space?

Comment: its just a gap between the two numbers

Comment: In which case the regex couldn't pick it up. So either don't treat it as anything or maybe you need to use the regex character that relates to one of any character. I don't actually know. I'm just giving ideas

Comment: Will try that yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(B?R(?=([\s_]))(?:\2\d+)+)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dVOraP/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(B?R(?=([\s_]))(?:\2\d+)+)` - Group 1: an optional `B`, then `R`, then one or more sequences of a whitespace or underscore followed with one or more digits (if you need to support letters here, replace `\d+` with `[^\W_]`)
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!.*\b\1\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\b\1\b` - the same value as in Group 1 matched as a whole word (not enclosed with letters, digits or underscores).

See a [Python `re` demo](https://ideone.com/8X2jRm) (you do not need the PyPi regex module here):

```
import re
LIST1=["AR BR_18_0138249",  "AR R_16_01382649",  "BR 16 0138264", "R 16 01382679" ]
pattern = r"\b(B?R(?=([\s_]))(?:\2\d+)+)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)"
for i in LIST1:
  rest = re.search(pattern, i)
  if rest:
    print(rest.group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the work:

```
[A-Z]{1,2}\s([A-Z]{1,2}+(?:_[0-9]+)*|[0-9]+(?:\s[0-9]+)*)
```

This regex gives below output:

```
AR BR_18_0138249
AR R_16_01382649
BR 16 0138264
R 16 01382679
```

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/hKSpiG/1)